# Loop Through 2 Arrays and Show Value Once

Tags: php, arrays

I'm looping through two arrays (gyms and games) and comparing the $gym['id'] value to $game['gym_id']. If the two values match, I display the game date and time as shown below.

```
<?php
$gyms = sw::shared()->gyms->getAll();
$games = sw::shared()->games->getAll();
?>

<?php foreach ($gyms as $gym) { ?>
    <?php foreach ($games as $game) { ?>
        <?php if ($game['gym_id'] == $gym['id']) { ?>
            <?php $match++; ?>
            <?php echo $gym['gym_name']; ?><br>
            <?php echo $game['date']; ?> <?php echo $game['time']; ?><br>
        <?php } ?>
    <?php } ?>
<?php } ?>
```

I am also displaying the gym name with $gym['gym_name'], but I only want the gym name to show ONCE and if that gym has games, meaning it would look like this:

```
GYM 1 NAME
GAME 1 DATE GAME 1 TIME
GAME 2 DATE GAME 2 TIME
GAME 3 DATE GAME 3 TIME

GYM 2 NAME
GAME 4 DATE GAME 4 TIME
GAME 5 DATE GAME 5 TIME
GAME 6 DATE GAME 6 TIME
```

How do I rewrite this?

Comment: echo the gym name in the outer loop, not the inner one.

Comment: No because that would show all the gyms, even if the gyms don't have games assigned to them. I only want to show gyms with games.

Comment: I think he means, only echo it at the end, so you get the last result.  Or set the value you're looking for to another variable and echo THAT out.

Comment: This looks like something a normalized database could solve very quickly.

Comment: @cpcdev try testing if the gym has games first before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this.

```
<?php
$gyms = sw::shared()->gyms->getAll();
$games = sw::shared()->games->getAll();

function getGymGames($gym){
    $gymGames = array();
    foreach ($games as $game) {
        if ($game['gym_id'] == $gym['id']) {
            array_push($gymGames,$game);
        }
    }

    return $gymGames;
}

?>

<?php
    foreach ($gyms as $gym) {
        $gymGames = getGymGames($gym);
        if(count($gymGames) > 0){?>
            <?=$gym['gym_name'];?><br />
            <?foreach($gymGames as $game){
            $match++;
            ?>
            <?= $game['date']; ?><br />
            <?= $game['time']; ?><br>
            <?}
        }
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not totally familiar with PHP, but why not make boolean to flag whether or not it has been displayed yet, and switch it once it is displayed.

```
<?php
$gyms = sw::shared()->gyms->getAll();
$games = sw::shared()->games->getAll();
?>

<?php foreach ($gyms as $gym) { ?>
 <?php $notDisplayed=true; ?>
<?php foreach ($games as $game) { ?>
    <?php if ($game['gym_id'] == $gym['id']) { ?>
        <?php $match++; ?>
         <?php if($displayed) { ?> 
          <?php echo $gym['gym_name']; ?><br>
          <?php $notDisplayed=false;?>
        <?php } ?>
        <?php echo $game['date']; ?> <?php echo $game['time']; ?><br>
    <?php } ?>
<?php } ?>
```